# Google Visualization API in Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, google-visualization

Im using the [Visualization API Gauge widget](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/gauge.html#Loading) in my Drupal 6 site.

Is it possible to set the value of the gauge dynamically by reading values from the database? Also, can the [GVS module](http://drupal.org/project/gvs) be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I should think so. You will probably need to create a custom module and include the javascript as drupal_add_js() to display the values you want. By outputting the js from the module you can set the values dynamically. I might have to include this in my current site, those graphs are sweet.